# Load translations from custom database with cacheing Zend Framework 2

Tags: caching, localization, zend-framework2, memcached

I want to translate tags with ZF2 using custom tables in database.I have two questions.
First i don't want to use ZF2 translator because as I understand it uses mo files, and than I have to load specifically my query results in those files, I don't want that. I want to write my function which will get translation tag as a parameter and than query the result for that tag in DB. I am not sure is this a good logic ? Any suggestions?

Second question, I want to create cache memory for that purpose. I don't want my translation function always to connect to DB and query every time the parameter(tag) from my DB. I want the script to load first time results from DB and than store in some kind of memory, so the second time the view file is called those results will be in that memory, so that the script doesn't connect to db every time. I searched solutions for this, i found that it can be done with memcached adapter in ZF2, but for that on server side that extension has to be enabled and installed. Any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I would generate a PHP file containing your translations, each time you make changes to the translation table.

Example file should look like this:

```
<?php
// lets assume file was saved to
// data/translations/en_GB.php

return array(
    'Text which should be translated' => 'Translated result',
    // more translations here
);
```

Edit your module.config.php:

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_GB',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'phparray',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../../../data/translations',
            'pattern'  => '%s.php',
            'cache'    => 'cache_adapter_id',
        )
    ),
),
```

In addition, you must configure the **cache_adapter_id** to make us of the cache mechanism of your choice (memcache etc.)